# How to bulk print using asp.net, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I enter roll no it displays name, marks obtained in all subjects and pass/fail of the student and I can print clicking on print button. But the problem is I want to print all students record continuously by clicking only one time on [Print] button.
I used loop like this

```
for(int i=1;i<studentno.count;i++)
{
     bindgrid(i); // i is the roll no of the student
     Session["ctrl"] = Panel1;
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onclick", "<script language=javascript>window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=300px,width=300px,scrollbars=1');</script>");
}
```

But it prints only the last one.

Comment: I am really having problem with understanding what Print.aspx does and what does printing mean in your head.Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

The `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` and your *Session["ctrl"]* variable will be overwritten at each iteration of the loop, so the script will only register at the final iteration and you'll end up with the final state of `Panel1` in your Session var.

It really depends on the behaviour of your Print.aspx page, but you could add all of your bound grids (in some format, perhaps HTML to String) into an ArrayList and put that into your *Session["ctrl"]* variable, then `RegisterStartupScript` after the loop:

```
ArrayList student_grids = new ArrayList();
for(int i=1;i<studentno.count;i++) 
{ 
     bindgrid(i); // i is the roll no of the student 
     student_grids.Add(current_grid); // where current_grid is bound grid at i (in some useful format)
} 
Session["ctrl"] = student_grids;  
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onclick", "<script language=javascript>window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=300px,width=300px,scrollbars=1');</script>");
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much. But i have one more problem at Print.aspx page that i got the following error message **** Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'System.Web.UI.Control'.

Comment: You must cast your Session var back to an ArrayList in your Print.aspx page: ArrayList student_grids = (ArrayList)Session["ctrl"]; From there use the ArrayList as necessary.

Comment: Can any one put the whole project?